# Ace code Editor with XML, hide specific xml attribute?

Tags: ace-editor

sorry, a newbie Q.  Is it possible to hide a specific attribute throughout an XML doc?

I need a way to synchronize the contents of the editor with non-Ace objects elsewhere on the DOM (unfortunately a SWF file that loads the xml seperately...).  I thought to label each node throughout the doc, e.g. tag='1', so that if a node with a given tag is manipulated in Ace, I can just use the tag to figure out what exactly was manipulated (and vice versa, update Ace when the xml is manipulated outside of Ace).

Best that people do not manipuate these tags, hence wanting to hide them from view.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create folds to hide text, but i think for tracking changes it is better to use anchors which keep their position relative to text

```
a=ace.session.doc.createAnchor(row,col); // create
a.getPosition(); 
a.detach(); // remove when not needed anymore
```